# Curl: disable certificate verification

Tags: linux, curl

I am developing and I need to access `https://localhost`. I know the certificate will not match. I just want curl to ignore that. Currently it gives me the following error message:

```
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

Is it possible to tell curl to perform the access anyway?

Comment: Dup of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60750/does-curl-have-a-no-check-certificate-option-like-wget

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Yeah, you can do that. From `curl --help` or [`man curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-k):

> `-k, --insecure`
>
> (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL
>   connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be
>   made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default.
>   This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless [-k,
>   --insecure](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-k) is used.
>
> See this online resource for further details:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: right, I just found it myself. I looked for it yesterday and it was not there! :)

Comment: Whoa! What's with the snarky reply?

Comment: I still see the "(51) SSL peer certificate ... was not ok" message with -k

Comment: Downvoted for the snarky response. If you don't want to answer a question, just don't.

Comment: @Michael answering the question and asking people to RTFM are not mutually exclusive options (as I believe my answer to this question perfectly demonstrates). You can do both

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you can indeed, but usually a less snarky tone is appreciated by most people

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the difference between ServerFault (Eg, the impression you give people with RTFM) and Unix.Linux. Which leaves a better impression with end user and is more likely to get them to actually start RTFM? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230952/what-is-the-difference-when-using-find-between-name-and-iname

Answer (score 21):

`curl -k`  or `curl --insecure` does NOT fix this particular error condition:

```
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate
```

Comment: The SSL peer certificate error occurs when validation of the trust chain (not the actual certificate) fails. My first recommendation would be to update the CA bundle on the machine

Answer (score 6):

If you truly want to disable `curl` SSL verification, by default, for ALL use cases, you can do [as suggested in this Unix stack exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109649/22734):

```
$ echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Now should you do this? No, as this is avoiding security checks you should have in place... but if you really really want to do this, **caveat emptor!**